# Populating HTML unordered lists using jQuery with json

Tags: json, jquery, html-lists

I am learning jQuery so please bear with me. I am attempting to populate an HTML unordered list using the following code. The error I am encountering is:
HTMLfile: No such interface. The code breaks on the following jQuery library statement:
fragment.appendchild(script)

Here's the code (a fragment of a successful jQuery Ajax call).

Json contains ID and Name.

```
          success: function(data) {
        var $defs = $('<ul id="mylist"></ul>').insertBefore('#lst');
          $.each(data.d, function (index, list) {
            $(this).appendTo($defs).wrap("<li>" + list.Name + "</li>");
          })
        },
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't be sure, because there is not enough of your script here, but it may be that your `this` statement isn't pointing to an HTML element. Console log your `this` statement to see what it is. I don't know what data.d is, but jQuery likes to replace `this` statements when you might not expect it to.

Maybe show more of your code?

Learning to understand what `this` is in JavaScript can be hard enough for people new to the language, so I generally advise people to learn JavaScript, before learning jQuery. Otherwise I think it will take longer to learn JavaScript, and be harder, more error-filled learning experience.

Comment: Hi Bjorn. Your assumption is correct. 'this' was pointing to the json object instead of the DOM element.